# Create react app - Imported media keeps re-downloading with different "chunk" name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, media, create-react-app

So I have this video where I use a couple of times in my page, but I noticed in the network that everytime it gets called it re-downloads the file with a different name on the network:

[image]

Right now I'm importing the video as:

```
import idleStand from "assets/videos/idle_stand.mp4";

...
      <video
        autoPlay
        loop
        src={idleStand }
      />
```

I have 2 video tags and the src actually changes every second or 2 (as you can see on the picture there's `hit_ground` video too.

Not sure if this is about Create-React-App or the built in webpack on it, but how can I prevent it?

EDIT:
I'm can't do:

```
     <video
        autoPlay
        loop
        src="assets/videos/idle_stand.mp4"
      />
```

because it doesn't work

Comment: I don't think it's downloading the same video every time.  It's downloading a different *chunk* of the video every time.  [`206`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/206) means partial content and if you look at the sizes it's downloading, they are different for each chunk.  Are you sure that this is an issue?

Comment: That's what I was thinking too but I only have 1 file named `idle_stand`. I am not sure why is that happening. I am pretty sure that its the same file because I opened them 1 by one and it showed me the same video.

Comment: Ah I see, so it's the same video and react is just downloading it parts by parts?

Comment: I believe that's what's happening.  However, you also mentioned that you can't just set the `src` to a static location which is correct.  Whenever you write `import vid from "some/video.mp4";` Webpack translates that to some resource through its own loader system and populates the import name with the "webpacked" resource name.  It's bundling the video either to a data URL (if size is right) to save on network requests.  You can however "fix" that if you would rather point to a static location.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info then! :)